# Batch * wildcard replacement

Tags: string, batch-file, replace, wildcard

I have a string `base` of the form `*+*`. I want to get everything before the +.
For example, if `base=foo+bar`, I want to get `foo`.

I've tried doing it with string replacement

```
set left=%base:+*=%
```

But this results in `left` storing `foo+bar`.

Interestingly, string replacement works for getting everything right of the +:

```
set right=%base:*+=%
```

Is `+*` being replaced by `+` (i.e. the wildcard is substituting for 0 characters)? Is there a better way to accomplish my task?

EDIT: I'm actually doing this in a for loop. Therefore, delayed expansion is on and (I think) I need to use !. Full code here:

```
for /d %%d in (*+*) do (
    set base=%%d
    set right=!base:*+=!
    set left=!base:+*=! ::this part doesn't work
    if !left:~-2!==!right:~-2! ( ::do only if last 2 chars match
        copy %%d mirrors
        copy %%d\%%d_montage.bmp mirrors
    )
)
```

EDIT 2: Comments in code above are only for readability here on SO. ::-style comments may not work correctly in for loops.

Comment: What language are you writing in?

Comment: Judging by the syntax and the tag it's a Windows batch file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [this trick](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429):

```
@echo off

set "base=foo+bar"

set "left=%base:+=" & set "right=%"

echo Left=%left%
echo Right=%right%
```

**EDIT**: If you want to use the method inside a `for` loop, use it this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in ("one+two" "first+last") do (
   call :separate %%a
   echo Left=!left!
   echo Right=!right!
   echo/
)
goto :EOF

:separate
set "base=%~1"
set "left=%base:+=" & set "right=%"
exit /B
```

Comment: Works as intended, and I learned a few hacks along the way. Much upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had much luck with environment variable string replacement with wildcards, probably because of the right issue wOxxOm notes.

I'd tend to favor this method here:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=+" %a in ('echo %base%') do (
    set left=%a
    set right=%b
)
```

Comment: Yep, just thought about it, however instead of `'echo %base%'` I've used `"%base%"`.

Comment: You should use `"tokens=1*"`, just in case there are additional `+` on the right.

Comment: @dbenham There won't be.

Answer (score 1):

See http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

> To remove characters from the right hand side of a string is a two step process and requires the use of a CALL statement:

```
SET base=foo+bar
SET right=%base:*+=%
CALL SET left=%%base:+%right%=%%
echo %left%
```

Comment: I'm actually doing this in a for loop, so where would I need to replace % with !?

Comment: Maybe everywhere. Edit your question in the first post and add the relevant code.

Comment: Well, all you need to fix is add `call ` before `set left=`. Or you can use the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

you could substract the right side from the string:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "base=foo+bar"
set left=%base:*+=%
set "right=!base:+%left%=!"
echo %left% / %right%
```

but I suggest another approach:

```
@echo off
set "base=foo+bar"
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=+" %%i in ("%base%") do (
  set "left=%%i"
  set "right=%%j"
)
echo %left% / %right%
```